# How to convert one time format to Date javascript?

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have this weird format of dates `1640828010231` which I'm trying to convert to actual date using javascript. I'm using the following code.

```
new Date('1640828010231')
```

but it is giving me the current time. I have no idea what format that date is in. I have tried various ways. please help.

Comment: What date is it supposed to represent, do you have any clue…?

Comment: Around end December @de

Comment: `new Date('1640828010231')` -> `new Date(1640828010231)`

Comment: `new Date('1640828010231')` returns `Invalid Date` in Chrome for me, not the current date. Date isn't expecting a string but a number

Comment: Didn't work @VLAZ

Comment: What do you mean "didn't work"? Please elaborate. If I type `new Date(1640828010231)` in my console, it outputs `Thu Dec 30 2021 02:33:30 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)`

Comment: It didn't when I tried Date(Number('16.....'))

Comment: @user38264974t538 [I do not believe that](https://jsbin.com/jipuhoruha/edit?js,console)

Comment: But it did when I used new Date(Number('16...'))

Comment: [Can't reproduce that, either](https://jsbin.com/feyucutama/1/edit?js,console)

Comment: Please edit your question and include the exact code that is causing the issue. The current code in your question gives `Invalid Date` in node, Firefox, Chrome and Edge. It does not give current time. Maybe you were trying it without the `new` keyword? Then yes it will return the current time.

Comment: The [*Date* constructor](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-date) behaves differently depending on the number of arguments. When supplied a single argument, it behaves differently for strings than numbers. Given a string, it will attempt to parse it as for *Date.parse*. A number will be treated as a time value. So `new Date('1640828010231')` (i.e. the value is a string) will likely return an invalid date, whereas `new Date(1640828010231)` (i.e. the value is a number) will return a valid Date for 2021-12-30T01:33:30.231Z.

Answer (score 0):

It's timestamp,

Have a look to mozilla doc to understand better https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#the_ecmascript_epoch_and_timestamps